# Is it compulsory to use past participle form of verb in possessive form of verb?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement

In a passage there is written, "oil and coal are burnt mills and factories."

Can't I say,  "oil and coal are burn mills and factories"?

Comment: The original doesn't seem to make sense. Can you edit to give the full sentence (maybe even more of the passage)?

Comment: The original doesn't make sense because it looks like it should be "oil and coal are burnt **in** mills and factories."  Please double-check that you copied the text correctly.

Comment: Also, I think you mean **passive**, not *possessive*.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking about the passive voice.

The passive voice is formed from be+past participle.  If you don't use past participle the sentence is ungrammatical.

Your sentence "oil and coal are burn mills and factories" is wrong.

Please note the comment:  ".... are burn**t in** mills ..."